# Java. File processing. For loop Error

Tags: java, file, loops, for-loop, processing

So I have this loop that will take a line of text and set it to a string to be processed by a method.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()){
    String text = input.nextLine();
    processLine(text);
}
```

The processLine method is.

```
public static void processLine(String text) {
    Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
    while (data.hasNext()){
        String str = "hi";
        int tabCount = 0;        
        str = data.next();
        System.out.print(str + " ");
        if (str.equals("{")) {
           tabCount++;
           System.out.println();
           for (int i = 0; i < TAB_SIZE * tabCount; i++){
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }   
}
```

What is happening is that my tabCount isn't being increased but it is still doing a println. How can this be? This is the output.

```
public class Test1 { 
    public static void main( String[] args ) { 
    System.out.println( "This is Test 1." ); } }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: declare tabCount variable outside to the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tabCount` variable is inside the `while loop` therefore it is getting **reset** for every iteration i.e. it will always be 0

try

```
public static void processLine(String text) {
    Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
    int tabCount = 0;        
    while (data.hasNext()){
        String str = "hi";
        str = data.next();
        System.out.print(str + " ");
        if (str.equals("{")) {
           tabCount++;
           System.out.println();
           for (int i = 0; i < TAB_SIZE * tabCount; i++){
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating the `tabCount` variable inside the local scope of the while loop, so every iteration of the loop it is reset to zero. Move the declaration and initialization of `tabCount` outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

**tabCount** is forced to 0 in every iteration of the while loop. Do the declaration and initialization of **tabCount** before the while loop and leave only the postfix increment of **tabCount** inside the ***if* clause** of while loop. This way it will retain the correct **tabCount** value.